# Ionic 2 twitter embedded timeline disappears

Tags: typescript, twitter, ionic2

**I have the code shown below, however after the user leaves the view the time line disappears?**

The first time we go to the view the timeline is present but when we return the view disappears.

Here is my code

> In Index.html

```
  <!-- Timeline Twitter -->
  <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>   

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

> In Twitter.html

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid >
        <ion-row>
            <!--Timeline Twitter -->
            <a id="twitter" class="twitter-timeline"
               data-tweet-limit="10"
               data-chrome="noscrollbar nofooter"
               href="https://twitter.com/UnivLaRochelle">Tweet de L'université de la Rochelle</a>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

> In Twitter.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-twitter',
    templateUrl: 'twitter.html',
})
export class twitterPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        !function(d,s,id){
            var js: any,
                fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                p='https';
            if(!d.getElementById(id)){
                js=d.createElement(s);
                js.id=id;
                js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
                fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
            }
        }
        (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
    }
}
```

I tried several ways but I have not found any solution, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace ngAfterViewInit with this one

```
!function(d,s,id){
        var js: any,
            fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p='https';
            js=d.createElement(s);
            js.id=id;
            js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
    }
    (document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```